# Plotting two overlapping density curves using ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, density-plot

I have a dataframe in R consisting of 104 columns, appearing as so:

```
   id         vcr1       vcr2         vcr3  sim_vcr1  sim_vcr2  sim_vcr3  sim_vcr4  sim_vcr5  sim_vcr6  sim_vcr7
1 2913 -4.782992840  1.7631999  0.003768704  1.376937 -2.096857  6.903021  7.018855  6.135139  3.188382  6.905323
2 1260  0.003768704  3.1577108 -0.758378208  1.376937 -2.096857  6.903021  7.018855  6.135139  3.188382  6.905323
3 2912 -4.782992840  1.7631999  0.003768704  1.376937 -2.096857  6.903021  7.018855  6.135139  3.188382  6.905323
4 2914 -1.311132669  0.8220594  2.372950077 -4.194246 -1.460474 -9.101704 -6.663676 -5.364724 -2.717272 -3.682574
5 2915 -1.311132669  0.8220594  2.372950077 -4.194246 -1.460474 -9.101704 -6.663676 -5.364724 -2.717272 -3.682574
6 1261  2.372950077 -0.7022792 -4.951318264 -4.194246 -1.460474 -9.101704 -6.663676 -5.364724 -2.717272 -3.682574
```

The "sim_vcr*" variables go all the way through sim_vcr100

I need two overlapping density density curves contained within one plot, looking something like this (except here you see 5 instead of 2):

[image]

I need one of the density curves to consist of all values contained in columns vcr1, vcr2, and vcr3, and I need another density curve containing all values in all of the sim_vcr* columns (so 100 columns, sim_vcr1-sim_vcr100)

Because the two curves overlap, they need to be transparent, like in the attached image.  I know that there is a pretty straightforward way to do this using the `ggplot` command, but I am having trouble with the syntax, as well as getting my data frame oriented correctly so that each histogram pulls from the proper columns.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `df` being the data you mentioned in your post, you can try this:

Separate dataframes with next code, then plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gdata)
#Index
i1 <- which(startsWith(names(df),pattern = 'vcr'))
i2 <- which(startsWith(names(df),pattern = 'sim'))
#Isolate
df1 <- df[,c(1,i1)]
df2 <- df[,c(1,i2)]
#Melt
M1 <- pivot_longer(df1,cols = names(df1)[-1])
M2 <- pivot_longer(df2,cols = names(df2)[-1])
#Plot 1
ggplot(M1) + geom_density(aes(x=value,fill=name), alpha=.5)
#Plot 2
ggplot(M2) + geom_density(aes(x=value,fill=name), alpha=.5)
```

[image]

[image]

**Update**

Use next code for one plot:

```
#Unique plot
#Melt
M <- pivot_longer(df,cols = names(df)[-1])
#Mutate
M$var <- ifelse(startsWith(M$name,'vcr',),'vcr','sim_vcr')
#Plot 3
ggplot(M) + geom_density(aes(x=value,fill=var), alpha=.5)
```

[image]

Comment: thats a helpful step in the right direction! Slight clarification: I need one graph containing two density curves.  One density curve contains all values from the 'sim' variables, and ones density curve contains all values from the 'var' variables.  Hopefully that clarifies a bit.  I should've explained that better, so I'm gonna edit the question!

Comment: @bricevk I have updated the answer with the solution you want! Let me know if this works!

Comment: @bricevk Great! If you found useful this answer you could upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dplyr` package, first you can convert your data to long format using the function `pivot_longer` as follows:

```r
df %<>% pivot_longer(cols = c(starts_with('vcr'), starts_with('sim_vcr')),
                         names_to = c('type'),
                         values_to = c('values'))
```

After using `filter` function you can create separate plots for each value type
For `vcr` columns:

```r
df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(type, '^vcr')) %>%
  ggplot(.) +
  geom_density(aes(x = values, fill = type), alpha = 0.5)
```

The above produces the following plot:
[image]
for `sim_vcr` columns:

```r
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(type, '^sim_vcr')) %>%
  ggplot(.) +
  geom_density(aes(x = values, fill = type), alpha = 0.5)
```

The above code produces the following plot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I failed to explain my goal perfectly in the question, so I'm gonna revise it. For some clarification: I need one graph containing two density curves. One density curve contains all values from the 'sim' variables, and ones density curve contains all values from the 'var' variables. Hopefully that clarifies a bit. I should've explained that better, so I'm gonna edit the question!

Comment: Hey bricevk - I address this in the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to subset and prepare your data for ggplot is with gather() from tidyr which you can read more about. Heres how I do it. df being your data frame provided.

```
# Load tidyr to use gather()
library(tidyr)

#Split appart the data you dont want on their own, the first three columns, and gather them
df_vcr <- gather(data = df[,2:4])

#Gather the other columns in the dataframe
df_sim<- gather(data = df[,-c(1:4)])

#Plot the first
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(data = df_vcr, 
               mapping = aes(value, group = key, color = key, fill = key),
               alpha = 0.5)
#Plot the second
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(data = df_sim,
               mapping = aes(value, group = key, color = key, fill = key),
               alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

[image]

However I am a little unclear on what you mean by "all values in all of the sim_vcr* columns". Perhaps you want all of those values in one density curve? To do this, simply do not give ggplot any grouping info in the second case.

```
ggplot() + geom_density(data = df_sim,
           mapping = aes(value),
           fill = "grey50",
           alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Notice here I can still specify the 'fill' for the curve outside of the aes() function and it will apply it too all curves instead of give each group specified in 'key' a different color.

Comment: Very helpful.  Used this, and @Duck's answer above to figure it out.  Very much appreciated